# Differential Equations: Switching from a sum of unit step functions into a piecewise function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I've completed a question involving unit-step functions and would like verification on my working out and answers, particularly for the last part, as we are asked to express the solution explicitly without the use of any special functions, which I assume means to change the unit step functions into a piecewise function.

The question requires using Laplace Transforms to solve a second order ordinary differential equation.

After using Laplace transforms and employing both s-shifting and t-shifting theorem, my final answer for q(t) is as follows:

$q(t) = [\frac{1}{31}e^{-7(t-\pi)}sin(31(t-\pi))]u(t-\pi) + \frac{9}{31}e^{-7t}sin(31t)$

To change this into a piecwise function, I obtained the following, since the unit step function equals 0 before t = $\pi$, and equals 1 after t = $\pi$:

$$
q(t) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{9}{31}e^{-7t}sin(31t) &: 0 \leq t < \pi \\
&\frac{1}{31}e^{-7(t-\pi)}sin(31(t-\pi)) + \frac{9}{31}e^{-7t}sin(31t) &: t \ge \pi
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I apologise for my formatting if it appears weird, first time using Mathjax :p Anyways, using trig addition formulae and expanding the exponent for the exponential term, I simplified this into:

$$
q(t) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{9}{31}e^{-7t}sin(31t) &&: 0 \leq t < \pi \\
&\frac{9-e^\pi}{31}e^{-7t}sin(31t) &&: t \ge \pi
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I am asking this since in lectures and practice problems, we weren't asked to express the solution explicitly as a piecewise function instead of using unit step function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your question is?

Comment: I'd just like to have some verification on whether I changed from unit-step function into piecewise function correctly. More precisely, when a function f(t-a) is multiplied by the unit step function u(t-a) where a>0, does the function f(t-a) retain the horizontal translation of a units right when you change it to a piecewise function? In a lecture example, we had sin(t-2pi)*u(t-2pi), which changed to piecewise sin(t) for t >= 2pi. However, is this simply because of the identity sin(t-2pi)=sin(t), hence a 'coincidence', or rather that a step was skipped in the working out?

Comment: Will be asking one of the lecturers for more clarity during their allotted consultation time in ~2 hours, but my impatient self wanted to know the answer to this query ahead of time. Will comment what they say regarding this issue later on.

Comment: The only error I see is that in the last line you should have $e^{7\pi}$ instead of $e^\pi$.

Comment: Your MathJax looks good for first time. But standard functions like sin should have a backslash in front to format correctly. \sin renders as $\sin$ instead of *sin*.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWaylandBales for the pickup on the arithmetic mistake and for formatting help. As for what the lecturer said, I can't remember the exact phrasing, but I think the gist of what she said is that if you go from piecewise to unit step function format, you just represent it as a sum of functions multiplied by unit step functions (and the argument of the original trig function stays eg f(t)*u(t-a)). But if you go from unit step to piecewise, you shift the function's argument depending on the domain so that it matches u(t-a) where a>0 i.e. f(t-a)*u(t-a), not f(t)*u(t-a).

Comment: From this, my interpretation is that if we have a piecewise function for which sin(t), t >= a is part of, where a>0, the unit step function would include sin(t)*u(t-a). However, if we just had a sketch of sin(t-a), then converting back to the piecewise would involve sin(t-a), t >= a, not sin(t). Hence, for our lecture example, it would appear that sin(t-2pi) = sin(t) was just a coincidence arising from the trig identities/addition angle formulae